# Writing large amounts of data to a csv file

Tags: vb.net, streamwriter

I couldn't find anything specific to this so here goes.
I have a For Each loop where I want to write values to a csv file. Currently, I use a WriteToFile function:

```
Public Sub WriteToFile(stuff as string, morestuff as string, moremorestuff as string))


    Dim strFile As String = "\\SomeServer\somefilepath\WriteTo.csv"
    Try
        If System.IO.File.Exists(strFile) = True Then
            'rename with startdate and enddate. Always want to create new
            Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(strFile, True)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Stuff & "," & MoreStuff & "," & Moremorestuff)
            objWriter.Close()
        Else
            Dim writeFile As IO.StreamWriter
            writeFile = IO.File.CreateText(strFile)
            writeFile.WriteLine("Stuff" & "," & "MoreStuff" & "," & "MoreMoreStuff")
            writeFile.WriteLine(Stuff & "," & MoreStuff & "," & MoreMoreStuff)
            writeFile.Close()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("An error has occured in the WriteToFile subroutine: " & ex.ToString) ' & vbCrLf & strPlugin & vbCrLf & strVersion)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Rather than closing the StreamWriter after every record is written, is there a way to keep it open? Or should it be kept open?

I made some changes and came up with this. However, using this code, how would I create a header in the csv file?

```
If cur.Count > 0 Then
  Using writer As System.IO.StreamWriter = New IO.StreamWriter("C:\Temp\UWConditions.csv")
    For Each lrdata As LoanReportData In cur
      loan = session.Loans.Open(lrdata.Guid)
      If Not IsNothing(loan) Then
        For Each condition As UnderwritingCondition In loan.Log.UnderwritingConditions
          Title = condition.Title.Replace(",", "")
          Desc = condition.Description.Replace(",", "")
          UWName = loan.Session.Users.GetUser(loan.Fields("UWID").Value).FullName.Replace(",", "")
          writer.WriteLine(lrdata("Loan.LoanNumber") & "," & Title & "," & Desc & "," & UWName)
        Next
        loan.Close()
      End If
    Next
  End Using
End If
```

Comment: How much data are we talking? You might consider putting it all in a string array of sorts and then doing a single `File.WriteAllLines` at an appropriate point.

Comment: Well, you probably would want to put the loop between your opening and closing of the writer. It's just a matter of refactoring your code.

Comment: You could pass a reference to a StreamWriter to the method, although at that point there may be no point separating out the writing to file from the calling method. Also, you should call `.Dispose()` on a StreamWriter when you've finished using it; the [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) statement is handy for that.

Comment: You are calling this from a loop? So when there is an exception and the user sees a messagebox, what happens to the loop? I don't see any way to exit it gracefully. I guess you keep seeing the messagebox. You should either return a bool indicating success, or forego the `Try...Catch` and catch exceptions in the calling code.

Comment: You have two StreamWriters, where you could easily have one (also they have different names, does that seem strange to you?). Here is some code you could use to simplify things and properly dispose:         `Dim fileName As String = "\\SomeServer\somefilepath\WriteTo.csv"` 
        `Dim writeHeader = Not File.Exists(fileName)` 
        `Using writer = New StreamWriter(fileName, True)` 
            `If writeHeader Then writer.WriteLine("Stuff,MoreStuff,MoreMoreStuff")` 
            `writer.WriteLine($"{stuff},{morestuff},{moremorestuff}")` 
        `End Using`

Comment: Right, on that topic of disposal, when you had an exception, the writer wouldn't be disposed so yes you'd definitely keep getting exceptions. This is why we use `Using`. Or you could declare one StreamWriter outside your `Try` and dispose it in a `Finally` but `Using` is a lot simpler.

Comment: Dumb question but how do you post a comment with more than 500+ characters? I keep getting a message that says I have too many characters so I posted what I came up with as the answer.

Comment: Andrew: so far 10K records which is about a 5mg csv file

Comment: djv: derp! How did I miss the two streamwriters?!?  i like the way you think so I used part of your idea. Much appreciated